# Loading file to database from java code

Tags: java, mysql, database, file-upload

```
st4.executeUpdate("insert into model (category,subcategory,modelname,taxid,image,filename)
values ('"+forCat+"','"+sel+"','"+model+"','"+taxid+"',load_file('"+f.getAbsolutPath()+"'),'"+f.getName()+"')");
```

Query runs but file is not uploaded

Also tried

```
GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
```

Here f is a file object getting from file chooser.

Query runs on console without any error but file is not uploaded and image field is null.

```
insert into model (category,subcategory,modelname,taxid,image,filename) values ('NEW','NEWSUB','CRAZY TEST2','5',load_file('D:\Users\sams\Desktop\image006.jpg'),'image006.jpg');
```

Comment: do you receive any error?

Comment: There is absolutely too little info in order to answer this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: is the file size bigger then `max_allowed_packet` ?

Comment: Tried for file size of 30kb,320kb and 800kb not working.. VALUE in TABLES IS NULL and other fields are inserted successfully.

Comment: i assume the file is hosted on the same sever as mysql... are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: also you can check this thread : http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=38403

Comment: not getting any error after running query.

Comment: Running on localhost.

Comment: @sampopes which version of mysql? If you execute this think `mysql> insert into model (category,subcategory,modelname,taxid,image,filename)
values ('a','b','c','d',load_file('c:/file.txt'),'fileName.txt');` does it work? (Obviously using the right filename)

Comment: "D:\Users\sams\Desktop\image006.jpg" is the file location. Any possible problem with format?

Comment: but, if you execute it in the console, does it work?

Comment: doesn't work on console or from java code.

Comment: @sampopes so, the problem is not you java code, please try using a `txt` file? What is the data type of the _image_ column?

Comment: datatype is LONGBLOB cannot use text. I need image there.

Comment: D:\\Users\\sams\\Desktop\\image006.jpg works well..

Comment: Now How I'll be able to convert D:\Users\sams\Desktop\image006.jpg into D:\\Users\\sams\\Desktop\\image006.jpg in java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
insert into model 
   (category,subcategory,modelname,taxid,image,filename) 
values
  ('SSAS','SSAS SUB','CRAZY 10','5',load_file('D:\\Users\\sams\\Desktop\\image006.jpg'),'image006.jpg');
```

It works well..

Comment: Now the question for senior folks.. Why \\ or / works but not single backslash which is default for windows...

Comment: You need \\ because of the non-standard (in terms of SQL) string handling in MySQL.